# Where to find vs code directory /var/www/html/ in windows

Tags: php, liveserver

I want to setup a live server for php files as in this post shown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64542693/13872132.

The problem is I have no idea where to find the `/var/www/html/` directory. I am using Windows and VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver) says that, by default, it serves the workspace you are working in.

(Which makes sense, because hardcoding a test server directory into an IDE when developers generally work on different projects would be silly).

The answer you are refering to seems to be making the rather bad assumption that you'll be developing out of the main system web server directory on a Linux host (which is often `/var/www/html/`). (Don't do that).

Comment: When I follow the documentation I get an error saying 'PHP not found'.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the /var/www/html/ directory. There do seem to be a number of [related issues]https://github.com/brapifra/vscode-phpserver/issues) filed though.

Comment: So on windows I need something like Apache to create a live server?

Comment: No, you need PHP.