# Get today date with php file in ajax call in vscode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new in Ajax and php. I've got an homework assignment where I need to get the date with a phph file, with ajax call.
But the only thing I get is the function of the php file on the console.
these is my JS:

```
    getDate();
});

function getDate() {
    $.ajax({

        url: 'get_current_date.php',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#date").html(response);
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('There was some error performing the AJAX call!');
        }

    });
}
```

and this is the get_current_date.php:

```
<?php
echo date("d/m/Y");
?>
```

I am running this with vs code, and I'm using the live server extension (I checked for other API and it's working, so this is not the problem).
I need another extension? why the php function is what I get on the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use Live-server for PHP with autoreload on save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678203/is-it-possible-to-use-live-server-for-php-with-autoreload-on-save) - VSCodes live server doesn't support PHP by default.

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: How so? Did you try all the suggestions? I would probably recommend using a proper web server. You can use something like XAMPP or similar to get a complete development environment in one package.

Comment: "The function of the php file " - what does that mean? Did you install any PHP runtime, and a webserver?

Comment: @NicoHaase — It means the PHP source code is being returned because the webserver they are using, VS Code Live Server, is not PHP-capable (as per the duplicate)