# Can I use Visual Studio Code plugin Live Server instead of Xampp?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, backend

I'll try to learn PHP for back-end, to create a localhost is it really necessary to use Xampp ???
Because in the past I've got lot of unsolvable problems with Xampp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use Live-server for PHP with autoreload on save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678203/is-it-possible-to-use-live-server-for-php-with-autoreload-on-save)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Install PHP Server and Live Server from VS Code marketplace and use them instead of xampp

for more info please check the answers here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64542693/11236563